# Адаптация под мобильное устройство

Tags: html, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мобильной версии, элементы (кроме карусели) не адаптируются под ширину страницы при увеличении ширины экрана.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="headerInner">
        <h2 class="zao">ЗАО "ВОЛОК"</h2>
        <div>
            <p class="new_par">Производство и продажа пиломатериалов</p>
            <p class="new_par">Производство и продажа пиломатериалов</p>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-content w3-display-container obratnyu_s" >
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/slaider.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 300px">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/slaider2.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 300px">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
        <style>
            .mySlides {display:none;}
        </style>
        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showDivs(slideIndex);

            function plusDivs(n) {
                showDivs(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function showDivs(n) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
                if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
</div>

    <div class="row mt-30">
        <div id="main_form_wrapper">
            <div id="obr_s" style="width: 370px; margin: -402px 20px; background: lightgray; padding: 20px; height: 300px; min-width: 30%">
                <p style="color: black; text-align: center; font-size: 20px">Обратная связь</p>
                <form action="sendMessage.php" method="POST" id="main_form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="main_name" placeholder="Ваше Имя:">
                    <input name="email" id="main_email" type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email:">
                    <input name="phone" id="main_telephone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона:">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-head mt-20 mb-50">Отправить заявку</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
h5,.eschool .demo3 .excellence h5{font-size: 25px;}
h2{font-size: 36px;}
.btn{padding: 10px 20px !important;}
h1{font-size: 30px;}
.eschool .demo3 .header .video,.eschool .demo3 .header{margin-bottom: 0;}
h2.zao{ margin-left: 12%;}
.new_par{margin-left: 2%; font-size: 19px; margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 75px;}
.w3-content.w3-display-container {
    margin: 25%;
}
#main_form_wrapper {
    margin-left: -687px;
    margin-top: 400px;
}
```

Comment: important и margin-left и margin-top со всеми огромными параметрами удалите

Comment: Тогда блок, на компьютере внизу